# How to fetch ProcessBusiness key associated with the processInstanceId of a particular task?

Tags: camunda

I need to only retrieve the UserTasks and display the variables associated with the processInstanceId of that particular task. This is my usecase. Now I have done it but only thing I am not bale to retrieve is the processBusinessKey. Can you please suggest how to retrieve the processBusinessKey from that particular task?
  List tasks = taskService.createTaskQuery().active().list();

Answer (score 1):

As I know processBusinessKey can be set only in `processInstance` level so you can retrieve `businessKey` by

```
ProcessInstance processInstance = runtimeService.createProcessInstanceQuery().processInstanceId(processInstanceId).singleResult();
String yourBusinessKey = processInstance.getBusinessKey()
```

P.S. Assuming that you already got processInstanceId base on your question statement

or if not, you can use `tasks.get(i).getProcessInstanceId()` to get processInstanceId